# VBA Error for saving a newbook in a specific path

Tags: excel, vba

Are there any errors for my vba coding? I have entered the file location on cells B4 and file name on cell B5 in the workbook. I would like to create a new workbook with multiple named sheets. Could someone help me to check? Thank you!

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1()

Dim FiLe As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Period As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4") = FiLe
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5") = Filepath
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2") = Period

'Adding New Workbook
Workbooks.Add

'Saving the Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FiLe & Filepath

'Add new sheets with colored tabs
Worksheets.Add().Name = Period & "DTH&TPD"
Worksheets(Period & "DTH&TPD").Tab.ColorIndex = 39
Worksheets.Add().Name = "DTH&TPD" & "Claims List"
Worksheets("DTH&TPD" & "Claims List").Tab.ColorIndex = 39
Worksheets.Add().Name = Period & "Accidental Claims"
Worksheets(Period & "Accidental Claims").Tab.ColorIndex = 33
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Accidental Claims List"
Worksheets("Accidental Claims List").Tab.ColorIndex = 33
Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
```

End Sub

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filepath & File`  ?

Comment: I have entered the file location on cells B4 where the file has to be saved and save it as the file name on cell B5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When posting your code, it's good practise here to always provide a description of what the actual *problem* is.  Are you getting an error?  If Yes what is it, and on which line?

That said, try this:

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Period As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    FilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
    FileName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
    Period = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add() 'Adding New Workbook
    wb.SaveAs FilePath & FileName 'Save

    'Add new sheets with colored tabs
    AddSheetWithNameAndColor wb, Period & "DTH&TPD", 39
    AddSheetWithNameAndColor wb, "DTHTPD" & "Claims List", 39
    AddSheetWithNameAndColor wb, Period & "Accidental Claims", 33
    AddSheetWithNameAndColor wb, "Accidental Claims List", 33

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'turn off warning about delete
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True  'turn warnings back on
End Sub

'sub to add a sheet, name it, and change the tab colorindex
Sub AddSheetWithNameAndColor(wb As Workbook, sName As String, clr As Long)
    With wb.Worksheets.Add()
        .Name = sName
        .Tab.ColorIndex = clr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and it works perfectly! I will improve my description next time. By the way, may I know what is purpose of adding second sub?

Comment: Second sub is to avoid writing the same add/name/color code over and over: if you had more sheets to add then your code gets lengthy and more difficult to maintain.  You can benefit from abstracting even small pieces of code out into separate methods and calling them from your main code.